# Data stops being retrieved from Firebase database after a few Weeks

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore, google-play-services

I've got an Android application loaded in play store that uses Firebase password and email authentication and the real time database. This all works completely fine when the user has just logged in.

However maybe a few Weeks later data will stop being shown even if the data changes in the database, it almost seems as though the user is no longer authenticated.

Can anyone shed some light on what is happening? I'm not sure if it's a database problem or an authentication problem. I can provide any information needed

i don't have any ideas how resolve this

Comment: Are you authenticate user every time, user open the app or just one time. If one time then are you storing authenticated data inside sharedPref or secureStorage?

Comment: can check your firebase rules, it might be the problem that the access will be allowed only before a specific data.